# Sr Programming Language Install On Ubuntu 14.04 Compiler Errors

Tags: c++, c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

The SR Programming language is no longer being maintained, so I realize my chances of finding help on this issue might be slim. However, I need the language installed for classroom purposes and can't think of how to proceed.

Here's the seemingly sole source of information on the web about the language
http://www.cs.arizona.edu/sr/

The install package provides a Makefile for installation. However, running the following:

```
mkdir /usr/local/src/sr
cd /usr/local/src/sr
wget ftp://ftp.cs.arizona.edu/sr/sr.tar.Z
tar xzf sr.tar.Z
make
```

results in these errors

```
echo "#"               >paths.sh
echo "#  Created mechanically;  DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE."   >>paths.sh
echo "#"              >>paths.sh
sed -n >>paths.sh <Configuration  \
    -e 's/#.*//' -e 's/[  ]*$//' -e 's/ *= */=/' \
    -e 's/="*\(.* [^"]*\)"*$/="\1"/' -e '/^[A-Z0-9_]* *=/p'
echo ""               >>paths.sh
echo  >paths.tmp '/*'
echo >>paths.tmp ' *  Created mechanically;  DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE.'
echo >>paths.tmp ' */'
sed  >>paths.tmp <paths.sh \
      -n -e 's/"//g' -e 's/.*/#define &"/' -e 's/= */ "/p'
if cmp -s paths.tmp paths.h; then :; else cp paths.tmp paths.h; fi
cc -g     -c -o util.o util.c
util.c: In function ‘salloc’:
util.c:79:27: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]
     return strcpy (alloc (strlen (s) + 1), s);
                           ^
util.c: In function ‘strtail’:
util.c:94:14: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]
     int ls = strlen (s);
              ^
util.c: In function ‘setpath’:
util.c:221:25: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ [enabled by default]
     searchpath = alloc (strlen (evpath) + strlen (ifdir) + 100);
                         ^
cmp -s multi/uni.h srmulti.h || cp multi/uni.h srmulti.h
cmp -s multi/uni.c srmulti.c || cp multi/uni.c srmulti.c
cd sr;    make  CC="cc" CFLAGS="-g  "
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/sr/sr'
cc -g     -c -o main.o main.c
In file included from main.c:7:0:
../arch.h:147:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘--’ token
     ERROR -- no architecture selected
           ^
main.c:114:1: warning: conflicting types for ‘options’ [enabled by default]
 options (argc, argv)
 ^
main.c:114:1: error: static declaration of ‘options’ follows non-static declaration
main.c:53:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘options’ was here
     options (argc, argv);  /* process options */
     ^
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/sr/sr'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I figured that this might be a problem with the compiler version I was using. `gcc -v` returns `gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04)`, and the install files seem to be made to compile on earlier versions. I tried installing an earlier version of gcc such that `gcc -v` yields `gcc version 3.4.6 (Debian 3.4.6-5)`, but ran into similar yet different compiler errors. Perhaps I did something wrong with the downgraded install because it seems weird that it says `Debian 3.4.6-5`.

The package also provides a `install.sh` file. Trying

```
chmod +x /usr/local/src/sr/install.sh
/usr/local/src/sr/install.sh
```

returns the following:

```
+ cp sr/sr /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot stat ‘sr/sr’: No such file or directory
+ strip /usr/local/bin/sr
strip: Warning: '/usr/local/bin/sr' is not an ordinary file
+ cp srl/srl /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot stat ‘srl/srl’: No such file or directory
+ strip /usr/local/bin/srl
strip: Warning: '/usr/local/bin/srl' is not an ordinary file
+ cp srm/srm /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot stat ‘srm/srm’: No such file or directory
+ strip /usr/local/bin/srm
strip: Warning: '/usr/local/bin/srm' is not an ordinary file
+ cp srprof/srprof /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot stat ‘srprof/srprof’: No such file or directory
+ strip /usr/local/bin/srprof
strip: Warning: '/usr/local/bin/srprof' is not an ordinary file
+ cp srtex/srtex /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot stat ‘srtex/srtex’: No such file or directory
+ strip /usr/local/bin/srtex
strip: Warning: '/usr/local/bin/srtex' is not an ordinary file
+ cp srlatex/srlatex /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot stat ‘srlatex/srlatex’: No such file or directory
+ strip /usr/local/bin/srlatex
strip: Warning: '/usr/local/bin/srlatex' is not an ordinary file
+ cp srgrind/srgrind /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot stat ‘srgrind/srgrind’: No such file or directory
+ cp preproc/*2sr /usr/local/bin
cp: cannot stat ‘preproc/*2sr’: No such file or directory
+ cp sr.h /usr/local/lib/sr
+ cp srmulti.h /usr/local/lib/sr
+ cp rts/srlib.a /usr/local/lib/sr
cp: cannot stat ‘rts/srlib.a’: No such file or directory
+ [ -f /bin/ranlib -o -f /usr/bin/ranlib ]
+ ranlib /usr/local/lib/sr/srlib.a
ranlib: '/usr/local/lib/sr/srlib.a': No such file
+ cp library/*.o /usr/local/lib/sr
cp: cannot stat ‘library/*.o’: No such file or directory
+ cp library/*.spec /usr/local/lib/sr
cp: cannot stat ‘library/*.spec’: No such file or directory
+ cp library/*.impl /usr/local/lib/sr
cp: cannot stat ‘library/*.impl’: No such file or directory
+ cp srmap /usr/local/lib/sr
+ cp rts/srx /usr/local/lib/sr
cp: cannot stat ‘rts/srx’: No such file or directory
+ strip /usr/local/lib/sr/srx
strip: '/usr/local/lib/sr/srx': No such file
+ cp srlatex/srlatex.sty /usr/local/lib/sr
+ cp preproc/ccr2sr.h preproc/csp2sr.h preproc/m2sr.h /usr/local/lib/sr
+ cp sr-mode.el /usr/local/lib/sr
+ [ ! -z /usr/man/manl -a -d /usr/man/manl -a ! -z l ]
+ echo not installing man pages for commands
not installing man pages for commands
+ [ ! -z /usr/man/manl -a -d /usr/man/manl -a ! -z l ]
+ echo not installing sranimator/srgetopt/srwin man pages
not installing sranimator/srgetopt/srwin man pages
+ [ ! -z /usr/man/manl -a -d /usr/man/manl -a ! -z l ]
+ echo not installing srmap/srtrace man pages
not installing srmap/srtrace man pages
+ exit 0
```

and nothing happens.

Can anyone make sense of these errors or at least give advice on how to proceed? It might seem futile because the language hasn't been maintained in a decade, but any advice would help me out tremendously.

Thank you

**Update:**
My Colleague provided these changes to the `./Configuration` file:

```
sed -i -e "s:/usr/local:/usr:" -e "s:/usr/X11/lib:/usr/lib:" \
  -e "s:CCPATH = /bin/cc:CCPATH = /usr/bin/gcc" \
  -e "s:RSHPATH = /usr/ucb/rsh:RSHPATH = /usr/bin/ssh:" \
  -e "s:VFPATH = /usr/lib/vfontedpr:VFPATH = :" Configuration
```

Running `make` on gcc 4.8.4 after this gives

```
cmp -s multi/uni.h srmulti.h || cp multi/uni.h srmulti.h
cmp -s multi/uni.c srmulti.c || cp multi/uni.c srmulti.c
cd sr;      make  CC="cc" CFLAGS="-g  "
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/sr/sr'
cc -g     -c -o main.o main.c
In file included from main.c:7:0:
../arch.h:147:11: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘--’ token
     ERROR -- no architecture selected
           ^
main.c:114:1: warning: conflicting types for ‘options’ [enabled by default]
 options (argc, argv)
 ^
main.c:114:1: error: static declaration of ‘options’ follows non-static declaration
main.c:53:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘options’ was here
     options (argc, argv);  /* process options */
     ^
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/sr/sr'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It gets rid of the initial pathing issues, but the compiler issues are still there.

With gcc 3.4 it gives

```
cmp -s multi/uni.h srmulti.h || cp multi/uni.h srmulti.h
cmp -s multi/uni.c srmulti.c || cp multi/uni.c srmulti.c
cd sr;      make  CC="cc" CFLAGS="-g  "
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/sr/sr'
cc -g     -c -o main.o main.c
In file included from main.c:7:
../arch.h:147: error: syntax error before '--' token
main.c:115: error: conflicting types for 'options'
main.c:53: error: previous implicit declaration of 'options' was here
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/local/src/sr/sr'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Rough guess: `./configure` first?

Comment: @Olaf Yes, thank you, I forgot to mention. There is a ./Configuration file that my colleague provided a replacement for. I'll edit the first post to include this.

Comment: Are you familiar with C and with Linux? If not, try to get help from someone who is familiar with both.  I guess that would be very simple for him. Very probably, he'll be able to install SR using a *recent* GCC compiler (the one usual in your distribution)

Answer (score 1):

---

"SR" : Old files → → year 2001 !

"SR" compiles OK with gcc version 3.2.3 or gcc version 3.4.6 (
Edit the file 'Configuration'. (
No gcc32 for Ubuntu 14.04 ).)

`# make install` : Provides /usr/local/bin/**sr**

P.S. : gcc34 is available for Ubuntu 14.04 :
compat-gcc34-3.4.6-ubuntu1204-1_**amd64**.deb, or compat-gcc34_3.4.6-ubuntu15_**i386**.deb

---